# What is the correct SQL syntax when sending parameters to a sp_exec_remote call?

Tags: t-sql, azure-sql-database

I am having trouble with passing parameters to a remote SPROC call using sp_exec_remote.  What is wrong with this syntax?

```
EXEC sp_execute_remote N'DevelopmentDBQueryDataSrc', N'pSelect_tReport', N'@StartDate datetime', @StartDate, N'@EndDate datetime', @EndDate
```

according to MS documentation:

```
 sp_execute_remote [ @data_source_name = ] datasourcename [ , @stmt = ] statement  [ { , [ @params = ] N'@parameter_name data_type [,...n ]' } { , [ @param1 = ] 'value1' [ ,...n ] }]
```

I keep getting this error:

```
Error retrieving data from shard [DataSource[mydatasource-hidden].database.windows.net Database=Development].  The underlying error message received was: 'Procedure or function  has too many arguments specified.'.
```

Here is the SPROC declaration:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[pSelect_tReport] (@StartDate datetime,@EndDate datetime) AS ...
```

**ADDITIONAL INFO:**
This is on Azure using an elastic query.   Permissions and master key have been created, set and tested.

```
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = <password>'; 
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL ElasticDBQueryCred 
WITH IDENTITY = <user>, 
SECRET = <password>;

CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE DBQueryDataSrc WITH 
    (TYPE = RDBMS, 
    LOCATION = 'myserver.database.windows.net', 
    DATABASE_NAME = 'MyDatabaseName', 
    CREDENTIAL = ElasticDBQueryCred, 
) ;
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

OK.  I figured it out.  It was syntax related. The params need to be listed again right after the SPROC name in the first nvarchar string:

```
EXEC sp_execute_remote N'DevelopmentDBQueryDataSrc',
                   N'pSelect_tReport @StartDate, @EndDate',
                   N'@StartDate datetime, @EndDate datetime',
                   @StartDate=@StartDate, @EndDate=@EndDate;
```

This will work.  It took some trial and error but I finally got it.  Thanks for helping me get to this conclusion.  I hope this helps someone else in the future.

Comment: That is weird, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used `sp_execute_remote`, but I am guessing that it follows the same conventions as `sp_executesql`:

```
EXEC sp_execute_remote N'DevelopmentDBQueryDataSrc',
                       N'pSelect_tReport',
                       N'@StartDate datetime, @EndDate datetime',
                       @StartDate=@StartDate, @EndDate=@EndDate;
```

That is, one parameter is a string with all the parameter definitions.  The parameters then follow as separate arguments.

Comment: With this syntax we get "The underlying error message received was: 'Procedure or function 'pSelect_tReport' expects parameter '@StartDate', which was not supplied" error.  Yes, the documentation does suggest that the functionality is the same as sp_executesql.

Comment: @redoc are you on a case sensitive collation?

Comment: Not case sensitive.  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Comment: @redoc . . . I think *server* collation is responsible for case sensitivity of column names, parameters, and the like.  You might want to check both servers (`SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('collation')`) -- or be sure that the names are exactly the same.

Comment: Column Names and params are exactly matched.   Error retrieving data from shard [DataSource=mydatabasename.database.windows.net Database=Development].  The underlying error message received was: 'Procedure or function 'pSelect_tReport' expects parameter '@StartDate', which was not supplied.  Unless I am misunderstanding something, the case is matched therefore is not the issue.  It is complaining that the value is not being passed.  Tried just sending @StartDate instead of @StartDate=@StarDate (which doesn't really make sense to me either).   Confused

Comment: Also just hard coded the values of @StartDate and get the same error.  Something must be wrong with the syntax as it is not recognizing the param.

Comment: @Gordon Just to clarify as well, the databases are on the same server instance (Azure database server) to the collation is definitely the same for each.

Comment: OK. I figured it out.  The params also need to be included directly after the SPROC name as such.